# How MapDataset captures user defined function from Python and inject into C++ implementation

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am getting started with TF and I am interested in **1)** learning how `tf.data` implementation works, in particular, on how the C++ backend captures/executes user *defined-function* by Python scripts.

I was expecting that C++ backend would use Python embedded approach, but apparently this doesnt happen; maybe because of performance hits in instantiating python interpreters on c++ for each example/batch. Instead, `tf.data` seems to transform user-defined functions by Python scripts in graphs on the C++ side, as mentioned in [this great video by TF folks at 5:15](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kVEOCfBy9uY&t=299s).

I have been trying to make sense of `python/ops/gen_dataset_ops.py`, `tensorflow/core/ops/dataset_ops.cc`, `tensorflow/core/kernels/data/map_dataset_op.cc`, `tensorflow/core/framework/function.h`, ``tensorflow/core/kernels/data/captured_function.h` without success. Any pointer on how to understand this flow would be truly appreciated!

Assuming user-defined functions are transformed in c++ graphs, **2)** does that mean that the user-defined function must use only native python operations or python classes/modules could also be used and "somehow" converted into C++?

Comment: According to https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/autograph/g3doc/reference/limitations.md, https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map the python to tensorflow function conversion uses either AutoGraph or tf.py_function, but I still cant find where this selection on how the python function will be called is still unknown

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_function explains a bit about running python on C++, but not much on its inner workings